# Table cell conundrum: trying to vertically center a link inside a table cell whose entire cell area is link-clickable

Tags: css, html-table, vertical-alignment, centering, tablecell

As you can see, in order to make the entire table cell link-clickable, I used `td a {display: block}`. The problem is `td a {vertical-align: middle}` no longer works with `display: block`. Not sure how else to center it vertically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I avoided using `line-height` because my link needs to be multi-line.

```css
table {
width: 300px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
border: 1px solid #000000;
height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

td a {
display: block;
height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>TEXT</td>
<td><a href="">LINK</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an auxiliar `span` and center it inside the anchor, so its content is free to move and align.

E.g.:

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

td a span {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>
      <a href="">
        <span>
          A VERY LONG LINK MAY BE LIKE THIS ONE, I GUES, RIGHT? HERE WE GO :D
        </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, bad solution. My link will have several lines, and with "line-height: 100px", it looks ridiculous.

Comment: Well, you should clarify sertain things when asking, thats why we can put reproducible examples.

Comment: Updated, check it, I hope it helps, you.

Comment: No, sorry. Now only the link itself is clickable. I need the entire table cell area to be clickable, not just the link.

Comment: That's right, I missed that on the first edit. Now I think it's fine to the specs.

Comment: Thank you, Leo. Your solution almost works for me, except for one weird issue. In my final code, I already have one `span` inside `td`. And introducing a second `span` messes up the font inside that `td`. Do you know what could possibly cause this issue?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the styling and seeing the actual behavior for that previous `span`, you can try with a higher specificity by using `td > span` (if you are not already doing it, of course). Or modify the selector I made.

Answer (score 1):

Added span in anchor tag and made a CSS change for the output

```css
table {
width: 300px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
border: 1px solid #000000;
height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

td a {
    display: table;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
}
    
        span {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            
        }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>TEXT</td>
<td><a href=""><span>LINK</span></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works too.